# Error in connection establishing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a database connection in asp.net in V.S 2015 using MVC 5 but I have found the error "Keyword not supported". I have not found any syntax errors. I am actually following a tutorial and according that I am doing it correctly. I tried to solve this from other sources but still get the same result .

Here is my code:

```
<add name="Default" connectionString="PAK-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database=asp; Trusted_connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SQLClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) is just a series of key/value pairs.  You forgot the key for this value:

```
PAK-PC\SQLEXPRESS
```

Should be:

```
Server=PAK-PC\SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: u mean i write connectionString="server="PAK-PC\SQLEXPRESS"??

Comment: @Adil: No, that's a quoting error.  I mean `PAK-PC\SQLEXPRESS` should be `Server=PAK-PC\SQLEXPRESS`.  Just put `Server=` as the key before that value.

Comment: yup its working thank u very much.. and sorry for this kind of mistake am new on asp.net and this is my first crud application.. thank alot.